# Note down time when a process stops

Tags: python, linux, unix, time, timestamp

I have started processing of several files. I noted down the (clock) time when the processing started. It is taking too long to finish and I want to go to sleep, but I want to note down the time when the processing stops. I do not want a very precise time reading, clock time is okay with me.
Is there any tool, or command or a small script that can help me achieve this.

Thanks for any help.

I am on an ubuntu 12.04 machine and running a single executable which processes multiple files.

Comment: Is it a script or code .. that u r executing nd want to note down the processing time (as it completes)..

Comment: As a linux user, you don't want to go to sleep when something is in progress. However, if your processing involves a shell script, have you tried `echo`ing the start and end time at the top and bottom of the script?

Comment: @Chronicles, it is a C++ program executable. It has already started execution. I was thinking in terms of a script which keeps grepping the pid of a process until it is not found and displays that time.

Comment: @Aditya Just try once the time command....as i mentioned in the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to write a python script which helped me out. The important requirement was that, i should be able to know the time (when the process stops) even when the process was already started. I hope the following script would help others who come across this question.

```
import datetime
import commands
import time
import sys 

def main(argv):
  if len(argv) < 2:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s <action>" % (argv[0],))
    return 1
  output = commands.getoutput("ps -e")
  while argv[1] in output:
    output = commands.getoutput("ps -e")
    print argv[1], " running", datetime.datetime.now() 
    #it should be set depending upon the precision a user wants.
    time.sleep(5)
  sys.stderr.write("Process finished at %s\n" % datetime.datetime.now())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tiny python script

```
import datetime
import subprocess
import time
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:])

while p.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(1)

sys.stderr.write("Process finished at %s\n" % datetime.datetime.now())
```

Example:

```
/tmp/watcher.py sleep 10
Process finished at 2012-08-19 10:38:11.233989
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out when a process finishes for both new and already running processes using [`psutil` module](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Classes) (cross-platform). It might provide better precision when `sleep()`-based solutions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Print the finish time for a process specified by <pid>.

Usage:
    process-finish-time <pid>
"""
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from psutil import NoSuchProcess, Process # pip install psutil

try:
    pid = int(sys.argv[1])
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    sys.exit(__doc__)

try:
    p = Process(pid) # OR use `psutil.Popen()` to start a new process
except NoSuchProcess as e:
    sys.exit(e)

name = None
while p.is_running():
    name = p.name
    p.wait() # block until the process ends
print("Process (%s) finished at %s UTC" % (name, datetime.utcnow()))
```

You can pass `timeout` to `p.wait()` if you want to do something while the process is running.

Answer (score 0):

Time command might help you

**Format**

```
$> time <command>
```

**For example** : if its a bash script

```
$> time sh Test.sh
```

**Output**

```
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Comment: since the process has already started, how could I use the `time` command. It would have been helpful if i used `time` command before starting the process.